Why such apathy towards double-counting of courses?
Many universities in the US disallow double-counting courses for double-major students. Why is that? The course content is basically the same, right?

Besides quibbles that the course content might be slightly different, there’s the larger factor that most US universities are primarily businesses. They sell credits, and departments justify their existence by how many credits they sell. So to them, you’d be asking for the final result (the degree) without paying enough.

Is apathy really what you mean?

Are you sure double counting is actually the issue and not that they're requiring a "for majors" version of a course? By saying course content is "basically" the same, that means it's possibly not the same? It would help to explain the specific scenario.

@Aruralreader I think the OP means antipathy

Are there really that many? My university allowed double counting up to half of the coursework required for a major. Usually the policy is quite permissive

Some double major programs will have credit hour requirements in addition to specific course requirements. This gives the student the opportunity (forced) to explore other subjects, enhancing the overall education.
Each major may have a minimum number of credits to qualify.
